# Filesystemerror(12) when opening App

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, file-connection

When I am opening app, sometimes it is not able to access the database and treat as there is no database available in the SD card.
This issue is not generated at the first launch of App. It is generated at the 3 or 4th launch of App.
I thought that when I am closing App, it doesn't close database connection and when launching App, it shows `'Filesystemerror(12) & Database is null or closed'` error and not fetching any data from database.

It is repeating again and again when I launching the App. When I restart the BlackBerry, it works fine. Because it was holding any database connection.
Please tell me how can I close all DB connections and sqlite Connection at the closing time of App.
Please give any solution for it and ask me, if you didn't get the problem.

Comment: Is this happening because of any connection doesn't close properly?

Comment: yes, you are right. It is happening when App closes and it doesn't closes the URI connection.
Please anyone of you tell me how to loose all the connections from database and any other files.

Comment: Your error message 'Filesystemerror(12) & Database is null or closed' does not look like a standard error I see coming from the SqLite API on BlackBerry.  Is that an exact, character for character copy of the message?  Is it coming from your application code, or directly from the SqLite API?

Comment: Also, what version of BlackBerry OS are you testing with when hit by the problem of the 3rd or 4th connection failing?

Comment: Hi Michael, As I observed from my code - any database or any file connection still remains open when I am closing the APp, and when I am opening the App and trying to create new READ_WRITE database/file connection then it is showing above mentioned error.
Can you please tell me the way to identify all opened connections and to close all at the time of closing the App, so that we can remove the same error.

Comment: How do you know the connection is staying open? Are you calling close()?   Also, what version of BlackBerry OS are you testing with? 5.0, 6.0, 7.0?

Comment: because, when I open the App treats as any connection already exists and showing `filesystemerror(12)` and this error is occurring when only any `READ_WRITE connection` remains open.
Also, I am using 6.0 and above 6.0.